# check if variable exist using if else bash script

Tags: bash

I try to write a very simple bash script file named `bash_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ];then
        echo $1
else
        echo 'no variable'
fi
```

in the terminal I tried to run `./bash_script.sh hello` but the output on the terminal is `no variable`. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-z` operator is true if its argument is an empty string. `hello` is not an empty string, so the `else` clause is taken.

Probably you meant to say simply

```sh
if [[ "$1" ]]; then
    echo "$1"
else
    echo 'no variable'
fi
```

Notice also [when to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (basically always, at least until you understand when you might not want to) and the preference for `[[` over `[` in Bash scripts.

But probably more idiomatically, just check if `$#` is equal to `1`, or larger than zero if you want to allow multiple arguments.  This will work the same regardless of whether some of those arguments are empty strings.

For completeness, the way to get your original script to take the `if` branch would be

```
./bash_script.sh ''
```

(or alternatively with double quotes instead of single around the empty argument).